# What does negative sign indicates in time complexity of a function if present?

Tags: time, complexity-theory

Consider some function have time complexity n-logn . So what negative sign indicating here .

Its complexity will include -logn and it will be less than n or it will include it as logn operations more and it will be >n????

Comment: n-log(n) is most likely n*ln(n) but badly written

Comment: Could you provide some context where you encountered this notation?

Answer (score 0):

The time complexity of an algorithm quantifies the amount of time taken by an algorithm to run as a function of the length/size of the input.

For example:

- linear search of an unsorted list: O(n), where n is the number of
  elements in the list
- bubblesort: O(n²), where n is the number of elements being sorted

Now, sometimes these bounds are an upperbound. And in such cases people tend to round up.
It's not really considered useful to say
This algorithm takes O(n² - 2n + 1) operations, since n² dominates 2n for sufficiently large values of n.

In your case, the algorithm being described has complexity O(n-log(n)).
Any mathematical function that yields a non-negative output for the input values n can be be used.
using -log(n) is not a problem.

Comment: How we should interpret negative sign in case of n- logn I will say operations can be more than n or less than

Comment: I would interpret this as "n minus log(n)"
rather than "between log(n) and n" because log(n) is typically a lot smaller than n. The range specified by "between log(n) and n" would simply be too large to be usable for realistic values of n.

Comment: If I am wrong please correct , if I have 2 algos one having complexity as n+logn and another n- logn let it can happen then which will take more operations and what - sign denotes in complexity

Comment: The algorithm that requires O(n+log(n)) will take slightly more time than the algorithm taking O(n-log(n)), but typically not much more.